# Event load order for XML project

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I'm trying to load XML data and then make it available for use for future methods.

Main.as:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip{

    var xmlM:XmlManager;
    var xmlGenerated:Boolean = false;

    public function Main(){
        trace("Main() called");
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
    }

    public function update(e:Event) {           
        trace("update() called");
        if (!xmlGenerated) {
            this.generateXmlContent();
            xmlGenerated = true;
        }
    }

    public function generateXmlContent() {
        trace ("generateXmlContent() called");
        var xmlM = new XmlManager("loaded.xml");
        xmlM.printData();
    }
}
```

XmlManager.as:

```
public class XmlManager {
    private var levelXML:XML; 
    private var myLoader:URLLoader; 
    private var dataString:String;

    public function XmlManager(file:String){
        trace("XmlManager() called");
        levelXML = new XML();
        var XML_URL:String = file;
        var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL);
        myLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL);
        myLoader.addEventListener("complete", startApp);
    }

    private function startApp(eventDataLoaded:Event){
        trace("startApp() called");
        levelXML = XML(myLoader.data);
        dataString = levelXML;
    }

    public function printData(){
        trace("printData() called");
        trace(dataString);
    }
}
```

When I load the data I get a trace of Main() called, update() called, generateXmlContent() called, XmlManager() called, printData() called, null, startApp() called, update() called.

This means all the code in main runs first including the enter frame method, xml class is generated but the data is not passed or generated as it returns a null.

To me this means that the Xml is not generate for me to use. I have read that XML loading in AS3 is asynchronous but using my boolean condition below still does not work as I am using this as means of generating the data in my update method in my main class.

Many thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you fix several mistakes in the code, it should work for XML loading. First one about variable that will store your xml raw data, and second one, how do you create XML:

```
private function startApp(eventDataLoaded:Event){
    trace("startApp() called");
    dataString = myLoader.data;
    levelXML = new XML(dataString);
}
```

You should wait for the XML, you can't instantiate Xml manager and instantly access loaded XML. Also It's not good idea to load XML in the loop, would be nice, if you load XML before starting main loop.

> Can you advise how one could wait for the XML to be fully loaded?

```
var xmlM:XmlManager;

private function Main():void {
    trace("Main() called");
    //Load xml first
    xmlM = new XmlManager();
    //Wait for XML
    xmlM.loadWithCallback("loaded.xml", onLoadXml);
}

public function update(e:Event) {
    trace("update() called");
    trace(xmlM.levelXML);
}

private function onLoadXml():void {
    trace("XML is loaded, start game");
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
}
```

And some small changes to XmlManager:

```
public class XmlManager {

    private var _levelXML:XML;
    private var _dataString:String;
    private var _loader:URLLoader;
    private var completeCallback:Function;

    public function XmlManager() {
        trace("XmlManager() called");
        _loader = new URLLoader();
        _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete, false, 0, true);
    }

    public function loadWithCallback(url:String, onLoadXml:Function):void {
        completeCallback = onLoadXml;
        _loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
    }

    private function onComplete(e:Event):void {
        trace("XML loaded");
        _dataString = _loader.data;
        _levelXML = new XML(_dataString);
        completeCallback();
        completeCallback = null;
    }

    public function printData() {
        trace("printData() called");
        trace(_dataString);
    }

    public function get levelXML():XML {
        return _levelXML;
    }

    public function get dataString():String {
        return _dataString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response.

I am new to ActionScript 3 and have yet to learn to ropes so taking it one step at a time. 

Can you advise how one could wait for the XML to be fully loaded?

Comment: Wow, thanks for the super answer. 

I started this question hoping for clues and hints as this is still an early learning journey for me but (what looks like) a full answer, many thanks Nicolas.

I will spend some detailed time looking through the code to expand my understanding.